# MySql get rank in a query

Tags: mysql

Here is my sample query:

```
SELECT userid,count(*)
FROM hits
GROUP BY userid
```

My table is something like this

id | userid | time ...etc

Where id is the primary key and I use this table to store every visit on a page.
Which means my table has 200,000+ rows.

For a userid lets say X i want to find out on which rank it is in the query that means how many users have visited that page more than the user with that userid.

I know there are many questions LIKE this but they aren't same because

1. My Query has group by
2. I tried quite a few answers here some don't even return anything while others take 5-10 mins. I need it to be faster.

for any further doubts pls clarify in comments

Thanks

Comment: Did you try nesting SELECT statements?

Comment: yes. It never gave a response there are more than 20,000 rows returned by this query. So .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count/Group by in a query that's expected to return multiple rows will get progressively slower because the query will still have to touch every row in the table. Generally, if you expect to do reports like this often, and you expect your table to continue to grow, you should begin rolling that value into a cached value (so you should store every result still, but you should also add to a counter on that user's user record). Of course, this also begs the question of whether you have an index on your user_id column and a foreign key into your users table, which should speed that query up considerably.

Comment: I want it in real time that's why i want to have a query that would work. Even if i DO follow this method that still means high system resource usage.

Comment: @kritya You won't have high resource utilization if you do it right. Every time someone visits, increment their number plus insert a row, 1 update statement should not screw up utilization unless you're doing something incredibly wrong. And if you don't need detailed info about the timestamp, don't insert another row. Although, you never answered whether you have an index on userid, which should be mandatory for that query. A query that examines hundreds of thousands of rows and returns 20k rows will be slow, and index will improve this, but you're still bounded by a log(n) of the total rows.

Comment: @kritya I'd also add that sometimes your original design choices aren't correct. This is one of those cases. One of the apps I work on handles 10M rows of data/day and does reports based on row counts for specific items, we would never be able to do it with the query you describe, so we roll it up and cache per timeframe. Big datasets sometimes require caching to offer timely answers. Some queries can't be optimized further.

Comment: I used the visit system to make the situation more simpler.
I cant use the increment because yes i necessarily do need timestamp because of shits on this and that day and etc...

Comment: @kritya So use both a counter to cache the value, and insert a row. Inserts and updates won't hurt you. What will hurt you is continuing to make that query. What makes you think that "Update users set visits = visits+1 where id = ?" is so bad? An update based on that user's ID should be quick. That way you have timestamped rows you can associate with activities for auditing, plus a way to make that query fast.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of having two :P But is there a way i can move my old to my new table ? Its VERY important for me to include that too in my rankings :D

Comment: You'd do an update statement based on the results of that query. It would obviously take a while for it to run, but that would migrate the values.

Comment: I am not that good at mysql lol. Can u pls tell some query or would it require aome php stuff ?

Comment: @kritya It would be something along the lines of UPDATE users SET total_visits = (SELECT count(*) from visits WHERE user_id = users.id);